# Should you tell your boss about an internal interview?

Tags: interviewing, internal-transfer

I have been helping another department (30% of my time) in my company as somebody left the role. Of course, I am doing this after my boss' approval. Now that department wants me to interview for the full-time position.

I think there is a decent chance (60-70%) of getting selected. They are also interviewing other candidates which have more experience than me. Chances are even if I get selected, I will have to work with my current boss in my new role because of cross-functional dependencies within company.

I am not too happy with my current job and my boss already is aware of my view on the current job. We are working to get this situation resolve.

My worry is that if I tell my boss right now and if I don't get selected for the new position within company, it may backfire more than if he know about it later on.

Should I tell or not?

Comment: Well you seem to have all the information. That's really up to you to decide, we cannot tell you what to do.

Answer (score 5):

I would **assume your boss knows or will find out**, given your description of the departments working together.

Given this, **I would tell him so that you can state your reasons in a positive way**.  If you do the interview without saying anything, it may communicate to your boss that you think the current situation is broken and you want to get out.  But if you talk to him, you could say something such as "I like this new position because of X, Y, and, Z.  I do appreciate how you are working with me on my current role, and I think we have been making progress, but I don't want to pass up the opportunity to work in a role that more closely matches my skills and interests."

Of course, this works best if you actually do have reasons other than getting away from your boss.